# Getting SVN files from multiple locations into one folder

Tags: svn

I'm currently using some configuration files from several project modules inside batch script(scriptx.sh) which tests the whole process.

scriptx.sh uses 3 configuration, one is from project xx(SVN location - project_name/xx/config), other from project xy(SVN location - project_name/xy/config) and last one from project xz(SVN location - project_name/xz/config).

Currently when I run this script I download every of these configurations manually before running it inside scriptx.sh working dir.

Is it possible to specify inside .svn folder (when looking at scriptx.sh working dir)SVN location of each of the configuration files so that they point to different locations? so they can be downloaded directly to working directory instead of doing the whole thing manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a single folder can only contain (versioned) files from a single SVN location.
You might want to checkout the repositories in subfolders and create symlinks in the main folder where you want files from multiple locations.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, can you please provide more info about this one "create symlinks in the main folder where you want files from multiple locations." links/tutorials anything that could be useful. tnx

Comment: Since you seem to be on a Linux box, have a look at the manpage of `ln`.
For example, you can use `ln -s subdir/somefile` to create a link named `somefile` in the current directory.